# mod_rewrite rule not working (pass parameter from one url to another)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

No matter how I modify this statement, I cannot get it to work no matter what. For example, I want to change from /path/to/class/Ad234Db to /path/to/class?code=Ad234Db. None of the following are working:

```
RewriteRule ^/?path/to/class/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /path/to/class.php?code=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^/path/to/class/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /path/to/class.php?code=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/class/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /path/to/class.php?code=$1 [L]
```

Also, the rewrite statement underneath that is still working:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located? Also you should show your full .htaccess as there might be conflicting/overriding rules.

Comment: What does not working mean? Do you get some error? 404, 500, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^path/to/class/([A-Z0-9]+)/?$ /path/to/class.php?code=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: By tweaking your answer a bit, I was able to find what worked. Thanks!